# I want the TextView to end in one Line...how to do it

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

i am developing an app, i would have linked an image but i don't have enough reputation to do so....my problem is The text doesn't fit in one line it goes to the second line,obviously thats because i have set the height to "wrap_content",but i want it to show the text only in one line and not 2 or more,what should i change the height to?i don't want any java code for this,my fragment is already heavy with lots of code,is there any way to do this on xml, so that it doesn't display different results for different screen size?also is there any way i can append "..." to the end of the name? like "backupRestoreConf..." or something like that?

Comment: use android:lines="1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set this in xml for your textview:

```
 android:singleLine="true"
```

Comment: Thanx is there any way i can add "...." to the end of the string??or i would have to use java code for that?

Comment: it will automatically add that. Use this to play around with your text: android:ellipsize=""

Comment: yeah i noticed that but its not the case with "android:maxlines" and what does ellipsize do?the same?

Comment: android:ellipsize="end". "..." is called ellipses. So you will have ellipses at the end of line

Comment: i can't differentiate what changes ellipses has brought in the display

Comment: yeah i accepted your answer ...i will give you a vote up once i have 15 repo,thanx for helping

Comment: ellipses has other options as well like middle, end, start. it will put ellipse in that place accordingly in textview. placing it at the end is default behaviour

Answer (score 3):

use `android:maxLines="1"` (or `android:singleLine="true"`, but it was deprecated and now it is not anymore. What to think.)

Comment: Thanx is there any way i can add "...." to the end of the string??or i would have to use java code for that?

Comment: use the ellipse attribute (start, end, middle, marquee)

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski : while I agree on the principle that one shoud always read the doc, it is not a reason to use harsh language. And there are many attributes in android views, one can be lost in them.

Answer (score 3):

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

Use this in your XML